# Creating variable names from varying lists

Tags: r

I am trying to create variable name from lists in R, but am struggling!

What I would ultimately like to do is to use previously created lists to create a formula for a multiple linear regression, whereby each value within the list will identify one of the explanatory variables of the regression formula.

I am starting with x lists of variable lengths (GoodModels_LMi, where i goes from 1
to x) and use each list to create a separate formula.

```
for (i in 1:x){
    lm(formula created from appropriate list)
    i<-i+1
    }
```

The lists correspond to variable numbers to be chosen from a data matrix (AllData). So for
example if:

```
GoodModels_LM1<-c(2,4,8)
```

I would like my regression formula to be:

```
AllData[,1]~AllData[,2]+AllData[,4]+AllData[,8]
```

I have been trying to use as.formula() and paste() to achieve this, however, I am not sure how to create the second part of my formula.

```
as.formula(paste("AllData[,",i,"]~",paste(?????????)))
```

I know that this below is not right, but is as close as I have come:

```
paste("AllData[,",paste("GoodModels_LM",i,sep=""),"]",collapse="+")
```

I have also looked into assign(), but have not succeeded as the value argument was the same as the x argument.

Thanks very much for any help with this!

Olivia

Answer (score 2):

Your formula should contain the column `names`, not the actual data. Here is a small demo using `iris`.

Imagine you want to run a regression using columns 2, 4, and 5 from `iris`. First, construct a formula using `paste()`:

```
vars <- c(2, 4, 5)
frm <- paste("Sepal.Length ~ ", paste(names(iris)[vars], collapse=" + "))
frm

"Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width + Petal.Width + Species"
```

So, the object `frm` is a string containing a formula that you can pass to `lm()`:

```
lm(frm, iris)
Call:
lm(formula = frm, data = iris)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)        Sepal.Width        Petal.Width  
           2.5211             0.6982             0.3716  
Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
           0.9881             1.2376
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried this out, but I still have problems with the second part of my formula that is now completely blank:

    frm<-paste("AllData[,",i,"[~",paste(names(AllData[,paste("GoodModels_LM",i,sep="")],collapse="+"))

For i = 1, this returns:

[1] "AllData[,1]~ "